# Ursina for Web?

Tags: python, html, ursina

Is there a way to compile ursina for HTML5 with WebAssembly or other technology?

I want to render my Ursina Game compatible for Linux & Mac (And Android/iOS with webview), but the multi-platform compilation for Python is... meh

Answer (score 0):

There is no Web support for Ursina. There only three platforms supported according to [official doc](https://www.ursinaengine.org/):

- Windows
- Linux
- Mac (not officially supported, but will most likely
  work)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I think Panda3D 3.11 will have web support, but for 2D basic stuff, you can use UrsinaCSS: https://github.com/pokepetter/ursina_css.

Comment: UrsinaCSS has long been deprecated in favor of Taptapir: https://github.com/pokepetter/taptapir So I recommend using that instead. Keep in mind there's not 100% overlap with ursina code, but can work with minimal changes, as long as it's 2D.